# Changed behaviour 0.76 -> 0.77 // always open these types of links in the associated app

Tags: google-chrome, protocol-handler

we've imeplemented an own protocol-handler "navision" in Windows. 
Until Chrome V0.76 we could open the links, click on "always open these types of links in the associated app", and everything was fine. 
Since Chrome V0.77 this checkbox is gone! (same behaviour in 0.78-beta and 0.79-dev)

[Difference between 0.76 and 0.77](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PFx3d.png)

Any idea, how to get the old behaviour back?

Thanks!
Florian

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There are two workarounds for this issue currently.

I am going to provide links:

https://support.google.com/chrome/thread/14194567?msgid=15347344

https://support.google.com/chrome/thread/14194567?msgid=15992019

I've tried the second one myself and it works.

Comment: both Link broken

Answer (score 0):

Awesome! The second link works fine.

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Google\Chrome\URLWhitelist]
"1"="navision://*"
```

It's not working with `HKCU`! Only with `HKLM`

I'm using the `chrome.amdx "Allow access to a list of URLs"` to publish this setting via GPO - works fine.